# Rendering SVG file to Image-object in Mono

Tags: image, mono, rendering, svg

Is there an easy way to render an SVG-image resulting in an image-object or a bitmap byte-array (Not saving the file in another type but just put it as an image in main memory)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a look at [Mono.Cairo](http://mono-project.com/Mono.Cairo), which is a low-level vector library for Mono. [Here](http://mono-project.com/Mono.Cairo_Cookbook#Opening_Images_.28Including_SVG.29) is an example for loading images, including SVG.